# Gitlab clone asking for password

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I have an instance of the following `docker-compose` file running:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest'
    restart: always
    hostname: '135.181.27.5'
    container_name: 'gitlab'
      #environment:
      #  GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      #    external_url 'http://135.181.27.5'
      #    # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '222:22'
    volumes:
      - '/var/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/var/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/var/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    shm_size: '256m'
```

I mapped port 22 to 222 since the port 22 is used by me to access the server.
Everything is fine but when I add a public ssh key to my gitlab instance and trye to clone a repo via the following command:

```
git clone git@135.181.27.5:root/python-demo-cicd.git
```

The result is:

```
Cloning into 'python-demo-cicd'...
git@135.181.27.5's password:
```

Is the problem the port mapping from 22 to 222?
If yes then how can I use port 222 instead of 22 for git purpose?

Comment: Are you aware you are still trying to clone from gitlab.com (at least that is what is in the question)?

Comment: I edited the command used.

Comment: is your key in `~/.ssh` or do you use an agent? have you verified ssh is actually trying your key? check if `ssh -v git@135.181.27.5` is properly trying to read your key (`debug1: Will attempt key: ...`)

Comment: `ssh git@135.181.27.5 -p 222` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default ssh port for `git clone git@host:path/to/repo.git` is 22, to use a different port change that to `git clone ssh://git@host:222/path/to/repo`.

You can add tthis to your `~/.ssh/config` to keep using short `git@host`, but that does not scale well for others...

```
match host 135.181.27.5 user git
port 222
```

Comment: What is the best practice for this situation?

Comment: Note: I found how to match host and user, so the .ssh/config workaround actually is feasible.

Comment: I think there is no one best practice to deal with this situation. I suggest to ask a dedicated question for how to deal with it.

Comment: options include: switch admin ssh to different port, add dedicated IP for gitlab.

Comment: Great didn't mention that.

Comment: I would change which port is used by sshd on the host and let gitlab have port 22. Less hassle for users.